# Slider values are taking from the database but it is not showing or slider is not working

Tags: php, mysql

[image]      
             
                
                    
                    
                    
                    
                
                 
                    
                        
                        
                        ";
                         }

```
                ?>

                <?php
                $get_slider="select * from slider LIMIT 1,3";
                $run_slider= mysqli_query($con,$get_slider);
                while ($row=mysqli_fetch_array($run_slider)){
                    $slider_name=$row['slider_name'];
                    $slider_image=$row['slider_image'];
                    echo "
                    <div class='item'>
                    <img src='admin_area/slides-images/$slider_image'>
                    </div>

                    "
                        ;
                     }

                ?>



            </div> <!-- carousel inner ends -->

            <a href="#myCarousel" class="left carousel-control" data-slide="prev">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-left"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
            </a>
            <a href="#myCarousel" class="right carousel-control" data-slide="next">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-right"></span>
                <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
            </a>
        </div> <!-- carousel slide ends -->
    </div> <!-- col-md-12 ends -->
 </div> <!-- container ends -->
```

The above shown is my code .there is no error and values are taking from database but only one image is showing and slider is not working

This is the screenshoot . only that image is displaying in the slider. in the below i echo ed rest of the images

Answer (score 0):

Your use of LIMIT  and OFFSET is wrong

```
select * from slider LIMIT 1,3
```

This selects only **1 Ro**w starting with the **third row**.

I think you meant

```
select * from slider LIMIT 3,1
```

This would give you **3 rows** starting from the **first**

Comment: did you also changed select * from slider LIMIT 0,1 this would give **no result** back

Comment: only changed the second one. and when echo the query its only displaying one image name.

Comment: can you please show the changed code, i can#'t see an error at all, Also could you please check your query in phpmyadmin, see how many rows it returns

Comment: there is no error showing. when checked the query in phpmyadmin it returned the required values

Comment: add $row_cnt = mysqli_num_rows($run_slider); before the while and echo it.

Comment: it returned "3"

Comment: could you please check if the files exists that are in $row['slider_image']; if you have no other errors, that's my lastguess